# How to create docker machine with specific version?

Tags: docker, version, docker-machine

When I create a docker machine like this,

> docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "my switch" vm

And set as active machine

> docker-machine env vm | Invoke-Expression

Then server version is updated to newer version (not stable version).
I'd like to use specific version so that matches with client version.

How can I?

my environment : windwos 10, hyper-v
current docker version : client 17.03.1-ce
new server version(updated version if i active new machine) : 17.05. something..